# Save search results and return a list of addresses

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a search loop through a column via manual input and picking information of columns further right of the found item.

I do not want to display the results immediately but at the end of the search as a table in a `Messagebox`.

Therefore I need some kind of growing memory stack or array, but I do not know how to implement this.

I got so far to write the code bellow, the search works, the Info-gathering not. Can somebody help ?

```
Sub Find_Tag()

Dim lr&, i&
Dim myTag As String
lr = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

myTag = InputBox("Enter Tag. " & Chr(10) & "Use the syntax bellow:" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "    J-XXXX")

For i = 1 To lr
    If Cells(i, "E").Value = myTag Then
        Cells(i, "E").Select
        Cells(i, "G").Select
        Cells(i, "P").Select

        MsgBox Cells(i, "E").Value & " " & Cells(i, "G").Value & "  " & Cells(i,"P").Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe create a userform with a listbox and add the items to it (avoids the max string length as mentioned by @Shai on @Vityata answer)?  I'd also use `Find` and `FindNext` as it's faster than looping through all the rows.

Comment: Agree with Darren. Or you could AutoFilter and work with the resuting range

Answer (score 1):

You can increment a message and show it in a `MessageBox`.
Something like this:

```
dim strMessage as string
dim strSpace   as string
strSpace = " "

For i = 1 To lr
    If Cells(i, "E").Value = myTag Then
        strMessage = strMessage & strSpace & Cells(i, "E").value
        strMessage = strMessage & strSpace & Cells(i, "G").value
        strMessage = strMessage & strSpace & Cells(i, "P").value

    End If
Next i

MsgBox strMessage
```

Comment: i thought of that, but what will you do if there are more than 100 matches, resulting in a `String` too large ?

Comment: @Shai Rado - The OP wants the answer in one line. With more than 30 it would be already ugly.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the input, it already looks pretty good. I added a "& vbNewLine" at the end of the last strMessage and it works well enough. I am not counting with too many results, so the stringlength should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with your code, except the useless `.Select` you are using.

```
Sub Find_Tag()
Dim lr&, i&
Dim myTag As String
Dim result As String
lr = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

myTag = InputBox("Enter Tag. " & Chr(10) & "Use the syntax below:" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "    J-XXXX")

For i = 1 To lr
If Cells(i, "E").Value = myTag Then
    result = Cells(i, "E").value & " " & Cells(i, "G").value & "  " & Cells(i, "P").value
    MsgBox result
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

This is the same as what you posted, are you sure you are targeting non-empty values?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will read the values from a column "E", "G" and "P" where the value in column "E" = `myTag`, into `StringArr` array.

And at the end of the loop, will dispaly each occupied array element in a `MsgBox`.

```
Sub Find_Tag()

Dim lr&, i&, j&
Dim myTag As String
Dim StringArr() As Variant

lr = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

myTag = InputBox("Enter Tag. " & Chr(10) & "Use the syntax bellow:" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "    J-XXXX")

ReDim StringArr(1 To 1000) '<-- init to large size , optimize the size later
j = 1
For i = 1 To lr
    If range("E" & i).Value = myTag Then
        StringArr(j) = Range("E" & i).Value & " " & Range("G" & i).Value & " " & Range("P" & i).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If
Next i

ReDim Preserve StringArr(1 To j - 1) '<-- optimize array size

For i = 1 To UBound(StringArr) ' display all array elements in message box
    MsgBox StringArr(i)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using `Find` means you also have a range to work with of found addresses (`rng2`)
- The code finishes by activitating the three column range of `E,G and P` where successful matches are made in E (`rng3`)

*code*

```
Sub PlanB()
    Dim rng1 As range
    Dim rng2 As range
    Dim rng3 As range
    Dim strMyTag As String
    Dim strAdd As String

    strMyTag = InputBox("Enter Tag. " & Chr(10) & "Use the syntax below:" & Chr(10) & "" & Chr(10) & "    J-XXXX")

    Set rng1 = Columns("E:E").Find(strMyTag, , xlFormulas, xlWhole)

    If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
        strAdd = rng1.Address
        Set rng2 = rng1
        Do
            Set rng1 = Columns("E:E").FindNext(rng1)
              If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                If rng1.Address = strAdd Then Exit Do
                Set rng2 = Union(rng2, rng1)
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    Else
        MsgBox strMyTag & " not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    MsgBox strMyTag & " has been found these locations: " & rng2.Address

 Set rng3 = Union(rng2, rng2.Offset(0, 2), rng2.Offset(0, 11))
Application.Goto rng3

End Sub
```